# How to write tests for custom gradle tasks

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have custom gradle tasks written in groovy, I want to test those tasks using JUnit or any other Mock framework, is there a way to do it, if someone can give an example it would be great.

Comment: Have you tried the user guide (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html)?